# Spring Boot Controller is not calling

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Application class in au.com.domain.demo package and my controller class au.com.domain.demo.control package. I tried to call get method in controller class, but it is not calling.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IssueTrackerApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("coming here.0000..");
        SpringApplication.run(IssueTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller class is:

```
@RestController 
public class IssueTrackingController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String hello() { 
        return "hello"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: my controller class is                                                                                              @RestController
public class IssueTrackingController {
   @RequestMapping(value ="/hello" , method = RequestMethod. GET )
 public String hello() {
  return "hello";
 }
}

Comment: Have you taken a look at the startup of Spring Boot in the log if you can see your defined end point ...?

Comment: how do you call the hello method?

Comment: When the application is up and you put a debug point in a line in the controller, do you see a green tick? Or an empty green box?

Comment: add basepackage in application class like: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ={"package"}) so it can find in particular package path.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try to follow an official tutorial from Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ - maybe it helps.

The other thing is - try not to return String from the method, but return an object instead. Spring Boot converts POJO classes to JSON.

Hope this helps :)